# How to read a jpeg image streamed from a server

Tags: c#, winforms, image, jpeg, tcpclient

I have a server that is constantly transmitting jpeg images like a time lapse video feed. I need to display these images in a C# WinForm TCP Client and am having issues with the streaming.

I have read a number of posts here and on other sites with similar issues, none of which have been able to provide a solution to my problem.

I have the following code that aims to retrieve the image from the server and display it using a PictureBox control: (there is header info in the image stream)

```
while (true)
{
    NetworkStream stream = m_client.GetStream(); //Get the data stream from the server

    //Load Image
    while (stream.DataAvailable)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[m_client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        string tempString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
        //split header info and data into separate strings
        string[] splitString = tempString.Split(new string[] { "]" }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
        splitString[0] = splitString[0].Replace(@"\", "");
        //split header info into separate strings for use later
        string[] imageInfo = splitString[0].Split('|');

        int size = Convert.ToInt32(tempString.Length);
        //int offset = splitString[0].Length;
        buffer = new byte[size];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        //Convert Image Data To Image
        MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        imageStream.Position = 0;
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(imageStream);

        //set the image display box properties
        VideoBox.Width = img.Width;
        VideoBox.Height = img.Height;
        VideoBox.Image = img; //Show the image in the picturebox
    }
    stream.Flush();
}
```

Currently this code runs as far as to `Bitmap img = new Bitmap(imageStream);` where it gives a parameter is not valid error.

This is the first time I have ever done this so am a bit lost on what to try next, I have spent the last day trying different solutions, but this one seems to be the best so far (I think :s).

I would appreciate if anyone can point out what I am doing wrong or missing.

Comment: Does the server transmit multiple images using single tcp connection?

Comment: I don't have access to the source, but as far as I know it sends out multiple images in a continuous cycle over a single connection.

Comment: I have this info: Video Protocol example \[VIDEO-FAULT\|2204771255\], Video Frame Packet example \[JPEG-VIDEO\|C2013\|FrameWidth\|FrameHeight\|DateTime\|ImageDataSize\]…ImageDataSize binary bytes forming image

Comment: Note, although it says video it is just jpegs being sent through

Comment: _"where it gives a parameter is not valid error"_ - would you please be so kind to show **what** error you get, and using what data? You'll have to look up the format being used. Is it valid JPEG data? Can you, to test this, save the bytes to a file and open it using an image viewer? Are you sure you capture the correct data, no spaces or leftover protocol data (like the brackets) in the data you assume to be JPEG?

Comment: I'll try saving it and opening in image editor, good idea. I don't think any protocol was left over, but I'll double check. Full detail of exception: System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to be able to pick single image from the stream. You may check if the server uses some kind of a transmission frame or maybe you have to inspect image header to figure out which part of the stream represents single image. Only if you have picked the data that represents the single image you will be able to pass it to Bitmap constructor.

When using TCP connection you have to explicitly introduce some frame format. Otherwise you won't be able to figure out where your content starts and ends.

Comment: I managed to pick out the header info from an image packet, and then had the remainder (which should be the image data) as a separate string. It all looks like jargon in VS2010 debugger though, and no matter what I put in the memory stream, it always gives parameter not valid. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with what